# Bluetooth error "Connection to Bluez failed"

Tags: bug-reporting

While opening Bluetooth GUI. got the error " Bluez daemon is not running, Blueman-manager cannot continue. This problem means that there were no Bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetooth daemon was not started.